# CSS Image not showing up on a CSS as background, but does when I insert it as an image

Tags: css

I have the following CSS at the root of the file (to check this issue Im about to explain):

```
.why-choose-us-image {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-position: center center;
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.why-choose-us-image.bg1 {
    background-image: url(assets/images/bigdog.jpg);
}
```

And Im placing that div on a background as follows:

```
<div class="why-choose-us-image bg1">
                        
</div>
```

But the image is not showing up. Even if I style="background-image......" the div, still not popping up on the background, but the image is there because it shows up if I insert it as an image! Super crazy.

Do you identify what am I doing wrong on the code? Thank you all.

Comment: Have you ensured the div's width and height are behaving as you expect? A div with no content and no `position` property set might not have a height, even though you've written `height: 100%`

Comment: is the css file and the html file in the same folder ? have you tried setting a border to the container or an height with a px value to check the height of your container and see where it stands?

Comment: Sean, the height and width were the issue. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Somehow I was getting a white image, but not it shows up after eliminating the height and width. So weird...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, because you should correct the address to your files

```
.why-choose-us-image.bg1 {
    background-image: URL(../assets/images/bigdog.jpg);
}
```

Or this because width and height not define

```
.why-choose-us-image.bg1 {
    height: 118px;
    width: 118px;
 }
```

Comment: Mahdigp, the css is on the root, thats why I call it straight to assets/images/bigdog.jpg. Actually, this works perfect: <img src="assets/images/bigdog.jpg"> and I see the image, I just cant place it as a background image.

Comment: can you tell me your folder and directory for this?

is it?

root/
root/assets/images/bigdog.jpg
root/index.html
root/style.css

Comment: It was the width and height. Thanks Mahdigp!